# Strange network activity virus when Aiport is off / No Wi-Fi

Tags: network, wifi, virus

So I have this strange issue on my aging MBP (pre-retina generation, running 10.8.5 (need this for Maya 2013 to run), where basically the network is always showing activity even when I am not connected...

I am starting to suspect that there is some kind of virus in play, maybe?

Could someone provide me with some advice. I have captured the activity in a short video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvZp5u1nPfw

Note that there are spikes in packets sent/received at about 0.17 seconds into it and again at 0.30 seconds...

How do I begin to diagnose this issue?

Thanks
- J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure to disable any Sharing, Airplay ect. and turn off your Bluetooth.

Here is a test you could run in Terminal:

```
Netstat -i
```

and look who is connected to what, by looking at the en0 (your wifi)

Answer (score 1):

The network traffic is common.

Watching your published video i noticed that you have Little Snitch running.

1. Launch `Little Snitch Configuration.app`
2. Enable the `Network Monitor` and `Show network activity in menu bar`
3. Quit `Little Snitch Configuration.app`
4. Enable/Show the `Network Monitor` by clicking in the new symbol in your menu bar
5. Hit the leftmost button and enable `Sort by last activity` and `Show local network`
6. Hit the 2nd leftmost button to show a visualization of the network traffic (red indicates outgoing traffic, green incoming traffic)

[image: snapshot]

By clicking on one of the processes (in my case the highlighted `check_afp`) all others are shielded in the visualizing part at the bottom and you are free to investigate any special activity.
Expanding the little grey triangle at the end of the row of a given process even shows the sources and destinations of the related traffic.

[image: snapshot2]

Now almost any culprit should be seizable.

- Sorry for any translation issues, i'm using the german interface and i translated it quick'n'dirty. But almost all menu entries are self explanatory.